# Rounded corners on StreetViewPanoramaView?

Tags: android, rounded-corners, google-street-view, cardview

I have a dialog which contains a CardView with cornerRadius set, StreetViewPanoramaView is at top, but top corners are square, I guess it's a SurfaceView, any hint about how to make the corners round above StreetViewPanoramaView?

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView
                    android:id="@+id/street_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" />

[...]
```

Comment: if you mask your `StreetViewPanoramaView` component does the corners look as intended?

Comment: I don't get how a mask can get around this, as the corners should be translucid, not masked

Comment: I meant hide `StreetViewPanoramaView` and check the result to be able to pinpoint the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"  maybe help you I am not sure because I used with another component not StreetViewPanoramaView so please try it.